# How to make cover image in post block expand to entire screen?

Tags: plugins, images, blog

I want to cover the entire width of my page with the cover image block, the one where you can write on top of it. If I need to add a code, please provide the code as well for CSS class. Or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to support [Wide alignment](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/extensibility/theme-support/#wide-alignment), the theme needs to add support for it. In the theme functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );
```

Then both `Wide width` and `Full width` options will appear in the block toolbar.